# How can I boot a Windows 2008 Server from DVD to do a clean re-install?

Tags: boot, dvd, windows-server-2008, reinstall

A few semesters ago, I took a Windows Server 2008 course, installing the OS on a machine I had lying about. I'm taking another server course in a couple weeks, and was going to do a fresh install since a.) I have no idea what my password is/was and b.) I have no clue as to the whereabouts of my password recovery USB stick. I just want to blow away to old version with a clean install.

Of course, Windows appears to have hijacked BIOS. Here's what happens after a single beep POST:

- f1, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f9 - Windows Boot Manager
- f2 - BRIEF flash of the motherboard
  manufacturer logo, then to Windows Boot Manager
- f8 - Advanced Boot
  Options (includes repair options requiring admin login) f9 - Windows
- f10 - Edit Boot options (current boot options:
  /NOEXECUTE=OPTOUT /HYPERVISORLAUNCHTYPE=OFF)
- f11, f12 - no boot interrupt

I tried booting from a bootable USB Linux stick, but no luck there; I suspect that's disabled/hijacked as well.

Are there any magic keystroke combinations to force a boot from DVD? Or am I looking at replacing the hard drive in order to do a clean install?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you access the BIOS?

Comment: Do you know the key to access the BIOS?? It usually is something like delete, esc or F8 or F12. Windows Server does not take over the BIOS to my knowledge.

Comment: I've tried f2, f8, f10, and f12; the only thing that I get any response from is f8, which boots to the server repair and install dialog...it ~appears~ as though Windows has hijacked BIOS. From a security perspective, this doesn't surprise me. If I can bypass a server boot, I've got access to all the data on it...but I could be wrong in that assumption.

Comment: I have never heard of Windows hijacking the BIOS, ever. If you want to make sure, simply remove the HDD from the PC (or disconnect the SATA cable) and boot the computer. It's possible you have a splash screen (Like a manufacturers logo) covering POST, or have fast POST enabled. You could pull the CMOS battery for a couple minutes to reset the BIOS to default. That should allow you to access it again.

Some additional info on your PC wouldn't go amiss either.

Comment: Additional PC info...good idea. Wish I knew what it was apart from an asus motherboard and parts cobbled together from other machines I had lying about. Let me rip open the case for a motherboard model number. +1 for CMOS battery idea. I always forget about that simple option. :)

Comment: @dwwilson66 I noticed you haven't mentioned if you tried the Esc or Delete keys. Asus: Delete, Insert, or F10 are the common BIOS keys.